# How To Add Links To Switching Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div that changes an image every 5 seconds and then repeats the loop. it gets the images from a folder. how can i link each image to a website or blogg?

HTML:

```
<div><img id="img" src="pictures7/1.jpg">7</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById("img").src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "pictures7/" + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = "pictures7/" + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= "pictures7/" + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

Comment: You wrap the image in a link tag and change the href attribute.

Comment: @Johan Van den Rym If i do that, all the images will have the same link and what i want is for each image to have its own link whenever it is being displayed

Comment: You change the href like you do with the src.

Comment: @Johan Van den Rym Can you please write the answer and show me how?

Comment: The problem is that I would like to see it working first. Can you drop your code in a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

jquery cycle is the best solution for this ( http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ ):

```
<div id="s1">
<div class="cell" id="s11"><a href="link1"><img src="1.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="cell" id="s11"><a href="link2"><img src="2.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="cell" id="s11"><a href="link3"><img src="3.jpg"></a></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){

$('#s1').cycle({
fx:     'fade', 
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
pause: true,
timeout: 5000 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you use one div to preview all the images? that's what my code does and that's what i need. what i need help in is whenever the image changes, the url has to change with it.

Comment: as i understood, at once only one image is visible. what i've posted, makes you able to link all the images, and click the visible one.

Comment: if you use this method, the image and the url around it changes together each div class="cell" means one item. these items autorotate in every 5 second. So the a href and the image is changing at once.